# Servidor http para Node.js

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js

eu instalei um servidor http para Node.js de forma global para rodar uma aplicação web. Quando inicio o servidor e tento acessar pelo "localhost:8080" ele dá mensagem: ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT
Mesmo iniciando o servidor em outra porta, quando tento acessar pelo browser por exemplo "localhost:8081" ele dá a mesma mensagem ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

---

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7OL3.png imagem do servidor inicializado

Comment: Você nem forneceu o seu código, como poderíamos sugerir uma resposta?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta dar um downgrade do http-server pra 0.9.0

`npm install -g http-server@0.9.0`

Da uma olhada nessa issue pra ver se ajuda: https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/525

Comment: Maravilha, funcionou!! muito obrigado.